# drag and drop ear file on wildfly to deploy project

Tags: wildfly

I'm trying to deploy my project on wildfly using drag and drop way.
In fact, I **drag and drop the ear project to wildfly server**, as result, I got `myProject-ear.ear.dodeploy` on *wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments*.
I want to have `myProject-ear.ear.deployed` instead of `myProject-ear.ear.dodeploy` after drag and drop the ear project on the server.

Have you please any idea about solving my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should just name the file myproject.ear then the deployment scanner will then add the control files, e.g myproject.ear.failed if it fails or myproject.ear.deployed if it works

Comment: Hello Sir @WillT, thanks for your reply. I agree but my problem is after dragging and dropping the ear project to wildfly server,  I got myProject-ear.ear.dodeploy in ordinary case, now, I'd like to obtain myProject-ear.ear.deployed instead of myProject-ear.ear.dodeploy. In other word, I'm asking if there's a way to obtain `deployed` project and not `dodeploy` project after dragging and dropping it on wildfly, so there's a way to restart wildfly once I drag and drop a project on it because when the server is started, **dodeploy** is changed **deployed**?. Thanks a lot Sir for your help.

Comment: Deployed will be created automatically once it finishes deploy, you should never create that file by hand

Comment: Yes of course Sir, you're right. I'm trying to obtain a deployed file automatically, once I drag and drop the ear project on the stopped wildfly. I mean: we suppose that the server is stopped, I want to make it started once I drag and drop the ear project on it. It's possible?. If yes, could you please help me doing that ?. thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: Simply having an ear file in the directory is enough to trigger deploy on boot. Have you not just tried this first?

Comment: Hello Sir @WillT, thanks for your reply. For the first time, I don't have any file on the folder deployments, after drag and drop the ear project on wildfly, the file `dodeploy` is created and after start the server the file is changed to `deployed`. **My problem is to have after drag and drop ear file on the server**, a started server _without starting it manually_ and obtain a `deployed` file automatically on the folder deployments .

Comment: You must have the server running, simply writing a file to the file system is never going to magically boot wildfly

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for your help. So there's any way to have _after dragging and dropping the project on wildfly_ a started server. Now, we suppose that the server is started manually, so could you please tell me how we can obtain automatically an opened bowser (welcome page of the project) just after drag and drop the project on wildfly which is started.

Comment: If you want a browser window to open automatically I suspect you deploy the ear into your own development machine. I see two ways to accomplish that: 1) the script that copies the ear starts up the browser with the correct URL 2) configure your webapplication with a ContextListener, and upon startup run an OS process that will trigger the browser with correct URL. Both these behaviours will be of little value once your code gets deployed to real servers.

Answer (score 0):

Whether drag&drop (or actually creating the war/jar/ear/... file in the deployments directory) is sufficient can be configured in the Wildfly configuration file (standalone.xml in your case). But since you create that file and see a ...dodeploy file popping up should tell you the deployment scanner has found your file and is acting.

Once the deployment finished, you should instead see a file named .deployed or .failed. In case of failure a log snippet inside the file could hint to the reason for failure.

But be aware of something: A drag&drop usually triggers a copy operation. Depending on the size of your file that copy may take some time. Wildfly's deployment scanner checks the directory every XXX seconds (configurable). So if your copy process started but the deployment scanner identifies the file before the copy is complete, Wildfly tries to deploy an imcomplete archive. This should result in an error message but may cause what you experience.

So it may be better to first copy the file to another directory (on the same disk), then just move/rename the file into the deployments folder - this operation is atomic, and the deployment scanner will immediately see the full file.
Another way would be to stop the deployment scanner completely and stop/start JBoss after every change to the deployments directory. This is anyway advisable if you run short on PermGen Space.